# Bubble sort function in Python

Tags: python

I have a question about a part of a bubble sort function that I dont understand. The assignment is to add detailed comments to all the parts of code explaining what it is doing. The lines of code that I'm uncertain about are number 2 and 3 (the ones marked with a '#?' at the end). Can anyone give a good explanation of what these lines are doing? Any help much appreciated.

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1): #?
        for i in range(passnum): #?
            if alist[i] > alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

list = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
bubbleSort(list)
print(list)
```

Comment: They're pretty much `for (int passnum = alist.length() - 1; passnum > 0; --passnum) { for (int i = 0; i < passnum; ++i) { /* ... */ } }`.

Comment: You should read the documentation of the [range function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). I linked it for you. All you have to do is carefully read what the parameters are, and get a better understanding at what the `for` loop is doing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
> ```

Per the [range function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

- `len(alist) - 1` is the length of the list (8) minus one (7).  It represents some "starting" number.
- `0` represents the "stopping" number.
- `-1` represents the "step" number.

These come together in `range(len(alist) - 1, 0, -1)` to say "count from 7 to 0, backwards - one negative step at a time".

> ```
> for i in range(passnum):
> ```

When `range()` is only passed one argument (a number), it counts from 0 to that number.  The documentation gives this example:

```
list(range(10))  
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So the code counts from 7 down to 0 - and every time it performs a single count, it immediately counts from 0 to that number.